# What causes the segmention fault in this memset()?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, memset

So I know a seg fault occurs but I can't pinpoint the internal logic behind it.
I believe that it is because there was a failure to initialize a pointer before accessing it.
But what would trigger this in terms of memory.

ex code:

```
#include<stdio.h> 

int main(void) 
{ 
  memset((char *)0x0, 1, 100); //What causes this to seg fault
  printf("HELLO POFTUT.COM \n"); 
  return ; 
}
```

Also what might be a solution to this.
Thank you.

Comment: What do you expect that line of code to do?  What architecture are you trying to run that on?  Are addresses 0-99 writeable from user space on your system?   Where did you copy that code from?

Comment: Writing to the NULL pointer normally causes a crash. It is undefined behaviour.  You cannot expect it to work.  Normally, the MMU has been told to leave the first page of virtual memory unmapped so if you try to read or write to it, you get a segmentation fault because you are writing to invalid (unmapped) memory.

Comment: The `return;` in a function defined to return an `int` should get a compiler error.

Comment: 'internal logic' is your memset() attempts write 100 bytes to an address range that starts at address 0. Every major operating system *ensures* reading or writing to address 0 causes a fault (by default), to help catch the extremely common bug of uninitialized variables. More internally, UNIX-like OSes R/W protects some memory pages (Linux usually 4K pages), 'red zones', to catch stack overflows, e.g.  blowing out the top of the stack (that grows toward low memory), because it's *much* easier to find and fix explicit runtime access violations (faults) than to detect/find/fix memory corruption.

Answer (score 1):

The solution would be to not to write to arbitrary memory locations :-)

In more detail, the C11 standard states, of the `*` indirection operator:

> The unary `*` operator denotes indirection. If the operand points to a function, the result is a function designator; if it points to an object, the result is an lvalue designating the object. If the operand has type "pointer to type", the result has type "type". ***If an invalid value has been assigned to the pointer, the behavior of the unary `*` operator is undefined.***

That paragraph references footnote 102, which states:

> Among the invalid values for dereferencing a pointer by the unary `*` operator are ***a null pointer,*** an address inappropriately aligned for the type of object pointed to, and the address of an object after the end of its lifetime.

Note that that's not an *exhaustive* list, you'll probably still run in to trouble if you use `0x01` rather than the `NULL`-equivalent `0x00`. Unless you *know* that your implementation allows access (such as memory mapped I/O addresses), you really should only be writing to addresses where you know there's a C object of some description.

Comment: The C standard doesn't actually require NULL to be 0x00 as far as I know.

Comment: @Coffee, you're correct that it doesn't require the underlying *representation* to be zero, but a integer constant expression of zero in the source file will be treated as `NULL` (as per `C11 6.3.2.3 Pointers /3`).